# If statement in txt file in Python?

Tags: python, file

I have file with biological data:

```
name1, name2, quality, name3
AB,CC,43,AAskkd
AB,GC,12,edjj
AD,GG,13,dds88
...
```

I need to create a if statement to pick only rows where quality is greater than 20.
Usually I solve that problems using pandas. But in this case I cant install pandas on working machine, and need fast results.

Can I do it in another way? Reading line by line file, and check if that line is quality > 20 then save it to another txt/csv?
If yes, how?

Exceptet result:

```
name1, name2, quality, name3
    AB,CC,43,AAskkd
```

Comment: *"Reading line by line file, and check if that line is quality > 20 then save it to another txt/csv?"*  Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Have you tried using a loop and the `readline()` method?

Comment: You can use Python's [built-in `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#module-csv). Have you tried to write any code to solve this? If so, please include a [mcve] in your post and describe what the problem is. Otherwise, this question is too broad because it basically asks to write code for you.

Comment: Thanks guys for advices, I will try! :)

Comment: You could definitely do this easily with the built-in CSV or even just file reading library. I'd recommend looking up how to use it, then posting your attempt here after trying to get it working on your own.

Comment: OK, thanks. Now I know what to look for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open two files and read the data line by line. If the third column is greater than 20, write that row to another file.

```
with open("file_with_data.txt") as f, open("outputfile.txt", "w") as fw:
    for row in f:
        if int(row.split(",")[2]) > 20:
            fw.write(row)
```

Comment: Ou! Thank U! 
So it's possible to read and write in one command :O 
And that if. Looks easy, but I couldn't figure it out.
Good to knows. I need to learn more about pure python, not just pandas.

Comment: Even if it wasn't, you could perform the same function with two nested context handlers. But yeah, this is cleaner.